# If statement based on height of elements not triggering

Tags: jquery, css

I am having trouble with something that seems like it should be really simple.

I have a a banner with a certain height, and an image that is set to 100% width of the banner. When the window resizes, the image width grows with it, but I want to change the alignment to the top when the image height is larger than the banner height.

For instance, when the image height is < the banner height:

```
.image {
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

and when it is > the banner height:

```
.image {
    bottom: auto;
    top: 0px;
}
```

It seems simple enough, but I feel like I am missing something really stupid because I can't seen to get the event to trigger.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    console.log('Image: ' + $('.image').height() + 'px' + ' ' + 'Banner: ' + $('.banner').height() + 'px');
    if ($('.image').height() + 'px' > $('banner').height() + 'px') {
        $('.image').css({
            'bottom': 'auto',
                'top': '0px'
        });
    } else {
        $('.image').css({
            'bottom': '0px'
        });
    }
});
```

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kiaaanabal/r8u9hu9c/2/

Any help is much appreciated!

Thank you!

EDIT:

People that are smarter than I told me to remove the px, as I was comparing strings. The issue now is the event triggers like the image height is ALWAYS greater than the banner height, which is not truee (at least to me).

Comment: do not add `'px'`, you want to compare numbers, not strings

Comment: Don't append `px` when comparing the heights. `100 > 2`, but `100px < 2px`

Comment: Such a cute puppie, I can't get myself to close your jsfiddle :)

Comment: I know, I just want to look at that little face ALL DAY!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
if ($('.image').height() + 'px' > $('banner').height() + 'px')
```

to

```
if ($('.image').height() > $('banner').height())
```

The first code snippet is comparing strings, where the second is comparing numbers.

Comment: Doing this makes it trigger like the image height is ALWAYS greater than the banner height. This is so weird.

Comment: have a typo in selector, missing a dot

Comment: I knew it had to be something stupid! So many thanks! Change your answer to the typo and I will accept it :)